# Series.replace() doesn't change dtype according to replacements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When using the `Series.replace()` method in pandas, if not all the values to be replaced are present in the series, the original `dtype` is kept as the type of data for that series.

I'm trying to replace all string values by numerical values in a given series. If all the strings I want to replace are present on the series, then the result is a series with `int64` `dtype`. However, some of the strings listed in the `to_replace` parameter are not present in the `series`, because the function I'm writing aims to convert other samples of data that may contain other classes in that particular series; in this case, the new series `dtype` remains as `object`, and do not change to `int64` as expected.

`data['Functional'] = data.Functional.replace(['Typ', 'Min1', 'Min2', 'Mod', 'Maj1', 'Maj2', 'Sev', 'Sal'], [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])`

In the above case, the class 'Sal' is not present in the series; thus, the result is a series containing `int` numbers ranging from 1 to 7 (excluding 0, which is the replacement value for 'Sal'). If I replace a random cell in the series with the 'Sal' string, and run the command, then the result is a series containing `numpy.int64` values.

I want the result series to be specified as a numeric series (`int64`), so I can select series in my dataframe according to their type. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `data.Functional.replace(['Typ', 'Min1', 'Min2', 'Mod', 'Maj1', 'Maj2', 'Sev', 'Sal'], [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],regex=True)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `astype` you can define your series dtype:

```
data['Functional'] = data.Functional.replace(['Typ', 'Min1', 'Min2', 'Mod', 'Maj1', 'Maj2', 'Sev', 'Sal'], [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]).astype(int)
```